# Piping and redirecting with cat

Tags: bash, cat

Looking over the [Dokku source code](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/blob/master/dokku), I noticed two uses of pipe and redirect that I am not familiar with.

One is: `cat | command`

Example: `id=$(cat | docker run -i -a stdin progrium/buildstep /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /app && tar -xC /app")`

The other is `cat > file`

Example: `id=$(cat "$HOME/$APP/ENV" | docker run -i -a stdin $IMAGE /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /app/.profile.d && cat > /app/.profile.d/app-env.sh")`

What is the use of pipe and redirect in the two cases?

Comment: do you know what `cat` does? and what it does without arguments?

Comment: yes, I thought it was being used differently though.

Comment: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html might be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, both usages are completely useless.

`cat` without arguments reads from stdin, and writes to stdout.

`cat | command` is equivalent with `command`.

`&& cat >file` is equivalent with `>file`, assuming the previous command processed the stdin input.

Looking at it more closely, the sole purpose of that `cat` command in the second example is to read from stdin. Without it, you would redirect the output of `mkdir` to the file. So the command first makes sure the directory exists, then writes to the file whatever you feed to it through the stdin.

Comment: OK, it seems like these usages are partially due to the author's ignorance, but your second point might be key.

Comment: I wonder why this wouldn't work, maybe I'm looking over something: id=$(docker run -i -a stdin $IMAGE /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /app/.profile.d && cat "$HOME/$APP/ENV" > /app/.profile.d/app-env.sh")